# Excel formula require to get last number from specific character

Tags: excel-formula

I want to get just the number after the last underscore (`_`). How do I do that without splitting the string with the comma as a delimiter?

- `PSN_IDA8_776` = need to get 776
- `NXXT_FAEMNE_7905` = need to get 7905
- `PCBA_SAN_LUIS_441B` = Need to get 441B
- `MCOM_LUX_415_U` = need to get 415U

The following is working for `PSN_IDA8_776`

```
=RIGHT(I9,FIND("_",I9)-1)
```

but same formula not correctly working for `ABCA_SEA_3_SFA_809`

Answer (score 1):

Assume your data put in A1:A6

In B1 formula copied down :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,LOOKUP(9^9,FIND("_"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1))+1,99),"_","")
```

Edit:

As per Terry W's point out that the above formula will fail in string like : `TEST_30_20_10_AB`

Here is the testing data `A1:A7`, as same as Terry W's post mentioned

```
PSN_IDA8_776       
NXXT_FAEMNE_7905
PCBA_SAN_LUIS_441B
MCOM_LUX_415_U
ABCA_SEA_3_SFA_809
TEST_30_20_10_AB
TEST_aa_20_bb_10
```

My revised formula in B1, copied down :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,FIND("_"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),1)+1,99),"_","")
```

Result of the formula :

```
B1: 776       
B2: 7905
B3: 441B
B4: 415U
B5: 809
B6: 10AB
B7: 10
```

Comment: A pretty nice answer but it will not return the desired output for this string `TEST_30_20_10_AB`. How would you tackle this one?

Comment: Thanks a lot you are great export

Comment: Hi Terry W, sorry in reply so late, I missed your comment. Thank you for the comment, my formula will give wrong result in respect of your listed data. Here's my fixing formula as per my edited post.

Comment: Good edited solution :) I would only suggest you to replace `99` with `LEN(A1)` or `2^8`. And make sure to put `@` in front a user's name so the user will be notified.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))))+1,LEN(A1))
```

Broken down into separate formula:
C1:  `=LEN(A1)` - find the length of the original string.
D1:  `=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",""))` find the length of the string with the underscore removed.
E1:  `=C1-D1` will return the number of underscores in the string.
F1:  `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","|",E1)` - substitute the last underscore with an I-bar.
G1:  `=MID(A1,FIND("|",F1,E1)+1,LEN(A1))` - pull out the characters after the last underscore.

or for a VBA solution:

```
Public Function After_Underscore(Target As Range, Optional Delimiter As String = "_") As Variant

    Dim Last As Long

    Last = InStrRev(Target, Delimiter)
    If Last > 0 Then
        After_Underscore = Mid(Target, Last + 1, Len(Target))
    Else
        After_Underscore = CVErr(xlErrNA) 'If no underscore return an #N/A error.
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thansk a lot you are great export

Comment: Your formula will not return the correct result for these two strings: `MCOM_LUX_415_U` and `TEST_30_20_10_AB`

Comment: @TerryW  You're spot on there.  I was thinking of just the last underscore - not the underscore before the last number.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution requires the use of **TEXTJOIN** which is only available in Excel 365 and later versions.

```
=IF(RIGHT(TEXTJOIN("",0,--ISNUMBER(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","t/s"))),2)="10",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",100),SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),1)="_"))-1),100)),"_",""),MID(A1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("_",A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))),0))+1,LEN(A1)))
```

replace `A1` to suit your case. It is an **array formula** so you MUST press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** on your keyboard after entering it in the formula bar.

> The main logic is to find out if the last two sub-string (followed by underscore `_`) is a combination of `numeric + text`. If so, return the combination of both sub-string, otherwise just return the last sub-string.

Here are the sample strings I have tested:

```
| Strings            | Results |
|--------------------|---------|
| PSN_IDA8_776       | 776     |
| NXXT_FAEMNE_7905   | 7905    |
| PCBA_SAN_LUIS_441B | 441B    |
| MCOM_LUX_415_U     | 415U    |
| ABCA_SEA_3_SFA_809 | 809     |
| TEST_30_20_10_AB   | 10AB    |
| TEST_aa_20_bb_10   | 10      |
```

Comment: Thansk a lot you are great export